# Rearrange Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, stack

I would like to rearrange my df from this:

```
data = {'date': ['1/1/2022', '1/2/2022','1/3/2022'], 'ticker1': [11, 21, 31], 'ticker2': [12, 22, 32],  'ticker3': [13, 23, 33]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

to this (where the dates still correspond to the correct rows):

```
data = {'date': ['1/1/2022', '1/1/2022', '1/1/2022', '1/2/2022', '1/2/2022', '1/2/2022','1/3/2022', '1/3/2022', '1/3/2022'], 'ticker': ['ticker1', 'ticker1', 'ticker1', 'ticker2', 'ticker2', 'ticker2', 'ticker3', 'ticker3', 'ticker3'], 'price': [11, 21, 31, 12, 22, 32, 13, 23, 33]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Not sure what the best way is, transpose? Pivot? Stack?

Comment: `df.melt('date', var_name='ticker', value_name='price')`

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work:

```
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df.unstack('date')
```